# Can't test a post request in rspec and rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec2

I've been looking all over the internet, but I can't seem to get this to work.

All I want to do is send a post request and test the response in rspec.

Here's what I have in my controller_spec:

```
it 'my test' do
  post 'api/company_id', :parameters => {key => 'value'}
  response.should be_success
end
```

I get this error:
    unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)

This is on the line on which the post statement happens (second line in code block).

I'm stumped but any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's not a copy/paste error on your part, it looks like you're just missing a colon on `key`:

```
post 'api/company_id', :parameters => {:key => 'value'}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't work. I made the change you made and I get the same error.

Comment: There's no other syntax issue with the snippet you posted.  You should post the rest of your spec file in your question.

Comment: I figured out my error. The error was actually in the controller and not the controlller spec >.<. Sorry about that. I'll vote you up, and sorry about that.